# `dplyr::case_when` Evaluation error: object 'x' not found

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Does anyone know why `dplyr::case_when()` produces the error in the following code?

```
tibble(tmp1 = sample(c(T, F), size = 32, replace = T),
       tmp2 = sample(c(T, F), size = 32, replace = T),
       tmp3 = sample(c(T, F), size = 32, replace = T)) %>%
  mutate(tmp = apply(cbind(tmp1, tmp2, tmp3), 1, function(x) {
    case_when(
      all(x == F) ~ "N",
      any(x == T) ~ "Y"
    )
  }))

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: object 'x' not found.
```

I am using R 3.4.3 with dplyr 0.7.4 on Ubuntu 16.04.

The error message is quite confusing, since the following code works fine, which indicates that `x` is not missing:

```
tibble(tmp1 = sample(c(T, F), size = 32, replace = T),
       tmp2 = sample(c(T, F), size = 32, replace = T),
       tmp3 = sample(c(T, F), size = 32, replace = T)) %>%
  mutate(tmp = apply(cbind(tmp1, tmp2, tmp3), 1, function(x) {
    if (all(x == F)) {
      "N"
    } else if(any(x == T)) {
      "Y"
    }
  }))
```

Just for reference, the following code also works fine:

```
cbind(tmp1 = sample(c(T, F), size = 32, replace = T),
      tmp2 = sample(c(T, F), size = 32, replace = T),
      tmp3 = sample(c(T, F), size = 32, replace = T)) %>%
  apply(1, function(x) {
    case_when(
      all(x == F) ~ "N",
      any(x == T) ~ "Y"
    )
  })
```

Comment: @Maurits Evers and @www provided some really good alternatives. But the actual use case is more complicated than the example (more variables, more rules, handling of NA values), so a more flexible form is preferred (e.g., if-else or case_when). Do you know why the `case_when()` (which is more convenient than if-else) code produces the error?

Comment: Didn't @www give you the answer as to why `case_when` doesn't work? (*"The issue is `case_when` does not do row-wise operation."*) BTW, I don't get an error, but all the entries are `NA`.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Well, row-wise operation is possible if you put `case_when` in `apply`, see the updated example in the question. I think @www did not mention why "object x" couldn't be found. I am using Ubuntu 16.04, what system are you using, @MauritsEvers? Is it a platform specific problem?

Comment: @NickZeng If the posts MauritsEvers or I provided generate the desired outputs you to your example, please consider to accept one of the posts as the answer. If your actual use case is more complicated than the example you provided here, please consider ask a new question with examples that can actually represent your real-world data.

Comment: And just to reiterate: There's *no error* on my side when I run the first code chunk. However, all `tmp` entries are `NA`.

Comment: When you run `apply` on a data frame, you convert it into a matrix. I don't know what dplyr's functions do when given a matrix, but you probably don't want to do this anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this is a bug, probably related to the hybrid evaluator: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3422

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `case_when` does not do row-wise operation. However, we can simplify the code by using `rowSums` (which conducts row-wise operation) and `case_when`.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(151)

tibble(tmp1 = sample(c(T, F), size = 32, replace = T),
       tmp2 = sample(c(T, F), size = 32, replace = T),
       tmp3 = sample(c(T, F), size = 32, replace = T)) %>%
  mutate(tmp = case_when(
      rowSums(.) == 0   ~"N",
      rowSums(.) > 0    ~"Y" 
    ))

# # A tibble: 32 x 4
#   tmp1  tmp2  tmp3  tmp  
#   <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <chr>
#  1 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE Y    
#  2 FALSE FALSE TRUE  Y    
#  3 FALSE FALSE TRUE  Y    
#  4 FALSE FALSE TRUE  Y    
#  5 TRUE  FALSE FALSE Y    
#  6 FALSE FALSE FALSE N    
#  7 TRUE  FALSE FALSE Y    
#  8 FALSE TRUE  FALSE Y    
#  9 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE Y    
# 10 FALSE FALSE TRUE  Y    
# # ... with 22 more rows
```

Or since there are only two conditions, `rowSums` with `ifelse` should be fine.

```
set.seed(151)

tibble(tmp1 = sample(c(T, F), size = 32, replace = T),
       tmp2 = sample(c(T, F), size = 32, replace = T),
       tmp3 = sample(c(T, F), size = 32, replace = T)) %>%
  mutate(tmp = ifelse(rowSums(.) == 0, "N", "Y"))
# # A tibble: 32 x 4
#   tmp1  tmp2  tmp3  tmp  
#   <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <chr>
#  1 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE Y    
#  2 FALSE FALSE TRUE  Y    
#  3 FALSE FALSE TRUE  Y    
#  4 FALSE FALSE TRUE  Y    
#  5 TRUE  FALSE FALSE Y    
#  6 FALSE FALSE FALSE N    
#  7 TRUE  FALSE FALSE Y    
#  8 FALSE TRUE  FALSE Y    
#  9 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE Y    
# 10 FALSE FALSE TRUE  Y    
# # ... with 22 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `Reduce` and logical OR?

```
set.seed(151);
tibble(tmp1 = sample(c(T, F), size = 32, replace = T),
       tmp2 = sample(c(T, F), size = 32, replace = T),
       tmp3 = sample(c(T, F), size = 32, replace = T)) %>%
    mutate(tmp = Reduce(`|`, list(tmp1, tmp2, tmp3)))
## A tibble: 32 x 4
#   tmp1  tmp2  tmp3  tmp
#   <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
# 1 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE TRUE
# 2 FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE
# 3 FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE
# 4 FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE
# 5 TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE
# 6 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 7 TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE
# 8 FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE
# 9 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE TRUE
#10 FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE
## ... with 22 more rows
```